# What's the VERSION column in BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE of Spring batch meta tables?

Tags: spring-batch, version, metatable

I implemented some codes with spring batch.
After my batch worked, data have been stored in metadata tables.

I figured out that BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE and BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION have VERSION column and their version columns differ.

Could you tell me what version mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Batch employs an optimistic locking strategy when dealing with database updates, and this is where the `version` column comes to play. This is explained in details in the [Appendix A: Meta-Data Schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataVersion).

Comment: It's just as well you understood my question... Thank you very much for your great answer!